# How to inspect outgoing traffic from Acess Point

Tags: vpn, wireshark, access-point

I have Access Point which is connecting to VPN and create internal WiFi network of our company everywhere. Now I need to inspect what protocol for VPN is this AP using. I am not able to configure it, so I need to inspect this from packets which is AP sending outside. I would like to run something like wireshark on this AP and watching for outgoing traffic, but it is not so easy and I am not sure how can I do it. I was thinking about something like that - I can connect my PC to WAN port of this AP, and maybe I can run wireshark on PC, and I will see, what AP is trying to send to our VPN servers? Is this approach correct, or I need to do something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most easy way would be to configure a *monitoring session* on a switch the AP is connected to, to send all the traffic to another port or vlan, where you can sniff it with a wireshark.

Check how this is done on Cisco Catalyst switches: [configuring monitoring sessions on Catalyst switches](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/switches/catalyst-6500-series-switches/10570-41.html)

Similar technology applies to all other managed switches, but the configuration process depends on the vendor software.